# Celery daemon picks up task but it never gets executed

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I have a celery instance running on heroku on a woker dyno. I use it with django and djcelery and I use the following command to start it:

```
python manage.py celery worker -B -E --loglevel=info --autoscale=50,8 --without-gossip
```

I added a task to the queue but it never got executed. The logs show this:

```
Scaling down -7 processes. (This is a while before the following)
Received task: myapp.tasks.my_task[75f095cb-9652-4cdb-87d4-dc31cecaadff] 
Scaling up 1 processes.
```

But thats it, after this, the job didn't get done at all. I fired other tasks after this as well and all of them were successfully executed. The same issue was repeated a couple of hours later.

I have a few questions:
1. The "Received task ..." log line means that the celery daemon picked the job off of the queue, right? Why did the worker process become inactive?
2. Since my autoscale is set to 50,8, shouldn't there always be 8 workers? Why were all workers scaled down?
3. Is there any way to know that a task is stuck? What is the recommended failure recovery for such a case if the task being fired is mission critical.

My celery version is 3.1.9, django-celery version 3.1.9, redis version 2.6.16

Settings in django settings:

```
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'redis://:password@host:port/0'
BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```